# How can I set all JSON keys as column name in MYSQL select

Tags: php, mysql, json

In mysql table one of the column is json, I want to select JSON field and set as column name

Json field value for class 3

```
{"name": "xyz 1", "email": "xyz1@example.com"}
{"name": "xyz 2", "email": "xyz2@example.com"}
```

Class 4

```
{"first_name": "abc1", "last_name": "pqr1"}
{"first_name": "abc2", "email": "pqr2"}
```

I can set specific key as a column name like

```
select json_extract(my_tags,'$.name') as name from {table_name} where class = 3;
```

But I want all key values as column name in select result. The key values will be different each time
From the above example results column should be as follows 
    **name, email**

```
select {my_tags} as name from {table_name} where class = 4;
```

But for class 4, needs column name should be **first_name and last_name**

Comment: you can use PHP array function to get all keys as column first convert JSON decode then use array_keys and then implode

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that directly in MySQL. You could do something like this in a combination of MySQL and PHP. Query:

```
SELECT JSON_KEYS(my_tags) AS tags, JSON_EXTRACT(my_tags, '$.*') AS values FROM {table_name}
```

Then in PHP:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $tags = json_decode($row['tags']);
    $values = json_decode($row['values']);
    $data = array_combine($tags, $values);
    // process
}
```

This will give you an associative array which is the same as you would have got from the separate column queries you propose. You could `array_merge` $data into $row if that made processing easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can write query like :

```
select 
  json_extract(my_tags,'$.name') as name
  json_extract(my_tags,'$.email') as email
from table_name;
```

So your result will be :

```
name email
xyz  xyz@example.com
```

Comment: Yes but this keys will change it not static some times it will be age and name

Comment: if there is no name in json, then I guess it will show null for name. For age you can add same like name and email

Answer (score 0):

you can get idea from below example

```
select  * from json_table(json_keys('{"shop_name":"National Chemist","shop_address":"dfsf","shop_email":"abc@gm","shop_mobile":"4545","shop_license":"4543545","invoice_bill_format":"a4_gst_logo","invoice_terms":"sdfdfds","invoice_popup":false,"sms_pack":false,"sms_tempalte":"dfdsff"}'
),'$[*]' COLUMNS( name varchar(20) PATH '$'))
as t
```

it will give you output like this

shop_name 
shop_address 
email 
....